# Conjugate subgroups of finite simple groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I would like to know whether this is known or not. We start with some setting: let $G$ be a non-abelian finite simple group of order $N$. Let us denote

$$G=\{1=g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_N\}.$$

For any non-trivial proper subgroup $H$ of $G$, we define

$$H_i:=g_iHg_i^{-1}$$

(obviously $H_1=H$). With this setting, here are the questions.

**Question 1**: Is there a non-trivial proper subgroup $H$ such that $H\cap H_i\gneq 1$ for all $i\geq2$?

**Question 2**: Can we expect more? - For any non-trivial proper subgroup $H$ of $G$, $H\cap H_i\gneq 1$ for all $i\geq2$.

Comment: What does $H \cap H_i \ge 1$ mean? The intersection contains the identity element so it has size at least $1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt I think the meaning is obvious... It means that the intersection is non-trivial...

Comment: @DerekHolt Also, I think that the notation $N\lneq K$ is well-known in group theory - which means $N$ is a proper subgroup of $K$.

Comment: Sorry my eyesight is not good enough! I misread the symbol as $\ge$. I would just write $N < K$ for proper containment.

Comment: I think the answer to Question 1 is yes. Any subgroup $H$ with $|H|^2 >|G|$ would work, and I think there always exiists such a subgroup. This might be known already, but it would be possible to check it from known results and data.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: Here is an example that such H can exist (my guess would be that there always is one): Let $G = A_5$ and $H \cong A_4$. Since all its conjugates are isomorphic, $H$ and $H_i$ each are the even permutations on 4 of the 5 elements that $G$ permutes. Then for any $i$, there are $a,b,c,d,e$ such that $H = S_{\lbrace a,b,c,d \rbrace}$ and $H_i = S_{\lbrace a,b,c,e \rbrace}$ and then $(abc) \in H\cap H_i$.

Question 2: Not true for any G. Every finite simple group has a subgroup of prime order (Cauchy's Theorem) whose distinct conjugates all have pairwise trivial intersection.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, to show that the answer to Question 1 is yes, it is sufficeint to show that all finite simpleg roups $G$ have a subgroup $H$ with $|H|^2 > |G|$.

There is a complete list of the indexes of the maximal subgroups of the simple groups of Lie type on page 16 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5166), and you can use that to verify the property. For  $G=A_n$ you can take $H=A_{n-1}$, and for $G$ sporadic use theinformation you need is in the ATLAS of Finite Groups.